# How to send any numbered value from jsp page to another java page in Spring/jsp

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

i got jsp page and a Mycontroller class method 
i would like to get any number passed from my jsp page to java class
method  ?

In simple words passing an number attached with link (onclick )to the my controller class

This is my JSP-Page:

```
</div> <!-- cd-tab-filter-wrapper -->

        <section class="cd-gallery">
            <ul>
                <li class="mix"><img src="resources/img-1.jpg" ><a href="/mypage.jsp">David Pringle 
**//// pass 1 onclick to this image link click**
</a>
</li>  

            <li class="mix"><img src="resources/img-1.jpg" ><a href="/mypage.jsp">David Pringle 
**//// pass 2 onclick to this image link click**
</a>
</li>      
</ul>
<section>
</div>
```

This is the method I want to set the data to:

```
@RequestMapping(value ="/new" ,method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView newPage(@RequestParam________   ,Model model ){

        ArrayList<Student> arr = null;  ArrayList<Room> arrr = null;
        Student tt=null; Transaction tt1=null; ArrayList<Object> al=new ArrayList<Object>();
       }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `<a>`'s need to use the path to the controller, along with providing a parameter name and its value.  Based on the controller path, change this:

```
<a href="/mypage.jsp">David Pringle</a>
```

to something like:

```
<a href="/new?id=1">David Pringle</a>
```

where the parameter value of `1` is dynamic, so in the second link it would look like this:

```
<a href="/new?id=2">David Pringle</a>
```

Then in your controller:

```
@RequestParam(name = "id") String id
```

where "id" is the same parameter name from the jsp.